# Combining Values from SQL Table into a Second Table

Tags: sql

I have one master table in SQL Server 2012 with many fields.

I have been given an excel spreadhseet with new data to incorporate, so I have in the first instance, imported this into a new table in the SQL database.

The new table has only two columns 'ID', and 'Source'.

The ID in the new table matches the 'ID' from the master table, which also has a field called 'Source'

What I need to do is UPDATE the values for 'Source' in the Master table with the corresponding values in the new table, ensuring to match IDs between the two tables.

Now to Query and see all the information together I can use the following -

```
SELECT m.ID, n.Source
FROM MainTable AS m
INNER JOIN NewTable AS n ON m.ID = n.ID
```

But what I don't know is how to turn this into an UPDATE statement so that the values for 'Source' from the new table are inserted into the corresponding column in the master table.

Comment: Yes - sorry an UPDATE type statement (not INSERT) - will amend question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
   MainTable
SET 
   MainTable.Source = NewTable.Source
FROM
   MainTable
INNER JOIN 
   NewTable
ON 
   MainTable.ID = NewTable .ID
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
UPDATE MainTable
    SET MainTable.Source = NewTable.Source
FROM NewTable
WHERE MainTable.ID = NewTable .ID
```

Answer (score 0):

first alter your main table, then:

```
update a
SET a.Source = b.Source
FROM MainTable a
JOIN NewTable b
 on a.ID = b.ID
```